# why are languages generally either statically typed or dynamically typed (not both)?

Tags: dynamic, static

I don't understand this. I understand the pros and cons of each, but why don't languages like Python allow you to specify the variable type yourself at initialization and function argument types and return types when you wish so the interpreter won't waste time checking it at runtime, for programs or just parts of your code where speed is important, and not do it yourself when it isn't?

It just seems waste of time for users to switch between languages kind of needlessly in these situation and for developers of the language to lose some users or not have them use their language for all of their projects because of this.

Comment: The tradeoff is this: Statically-typed languages protect you by showing you the exact error **during compilation**, which makes it much easier to fix than when you get some "random" (i.e., not necessarily related) error **during runtime**. Dynamically-typed languages revoke the "burden" of knowing and declaring everything in advance. They sort of let you "do your thing more naturally", but they don't protect you from, for example, calling a member function or referencing a member variable that does not exist.

Comment: And of course, the generated executable is typically much more efficient in statically-typed languages than in dynamically-typed languages. BTW, some statically-typed languages like Java and C# deploy the reflection mechanism, which is rather close to what dynamically-typed languages have to offer.

Comment: I mentioned that my question is not about the tradeoff ("pros and cons").

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a variable (with a specific type) in a dynamically typed language would be pointless because the variable could be reassigned with a different type later on. And the type of the variable is determined by the variable to which it is assigned anyway. So making statically typing variables optional wouldn't actually provide any extra functionality.

Second, compile-time checking of function arguments wouldn't work either because the type of the variables passed to it couldn't be determined until runtime. And functions can be coded to check the types of their own arguments in a dynamically typed language, so there's no need to implement another system for this.

Comment: Your points are why it wouldn't work because of how the Python works right now. I never said I expected a language which had this feature to work the same way Python does now. By that I mean this: "variable could be reassigned with a different type later on". Well a simple solution then: throw an error message when a statically typed variable is attempted to be changed to a different type. Same with function arguments: if a variable whose type has not been specified is used as an argument for a function like this, throw an error message.

Comment: @LeoErvin What you're implying is a statically typed language where all variables are by "default" declared subclasses of one root. For example, `Object` in Java. You can achieve the same effect by doing this.